# Strange Docker + Celery Bug

Tags: python, docker, celery

I am trying to run celery inside a docker container and its never updating for some reason. Whenever I add a new function in `tasks.py` or update an existing function it never registers with celery even after I restart the container.

Here is my `dockerfile`:

```
# start with a base image
FROM python:3.4-slim

ENV REDIS_IP 1.1.1.111
ENV REDIS_PORT 6379
ENV REDIS_DB 0

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
apt-utils \
nginx \
supervisor \
python3-pip \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "America/New_York" > /etc/timezone; dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

# update working directories
ADD ./app /app
ADD ./config /config
ADD requirements.txt /

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# setup config
RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

RUN ln -s /config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
RUN ln -s /config/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

Then my `supervisor.conf`:

```
[program:app]
command = uwsgi --ini /config/app.ini
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:nginx]
command = service nginx restart
autostart=true
autorestart=true

[program:celery]
directory = /app
command = celery -A tasks.celery worker -P eventlet -c 1000
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

My `tasks.py`:

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from app import app as flask_app

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend='redis://{0}:{1}/{2}'.format(os.environ['REDIS_IP'],os.environ['REDIS_PORT'],os.environ['REDIS_DB']),
                    broker='redis://{0}:{1}/{2}'.format(os.environ['REDIS_IP'],os.environ['REDIS_PORT'],os.environ['REDIS_DB']))
    celery.conf.update(
        CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True,
        CELERY_TIMEZONE='America/New_York'
    )
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery = make_celery(flask_app)

@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a+ b

@celery.task()
def multiply(a,b)
    return a*b
```

and for some reason:

- I have 21 workers registered and `multiply` never gets registered,
- also when I make changes to `add_together`, that never registers as well, even when I restart the container.

[image]

I am starting my container with:

```
docker build --rm -t myapp .
docker run -d -p 88:80 -v $(pwd)/app:/app --name=myapp myapp
```

and restart with:

```
docker restart myapp
```

I have also tried

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

and then rebuilding the app all over again. Nothing helps. Any ideas would be very much so appreciated.

Comment: do you rebuild with `--no-cache`?

Comment: @user2915097 I get `unknown flag: --no-cache`

Comment: at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ I see `--no-cache                Do not use cache when building the image`

Comment: @user2915097 my apologies, I tried that as well it didnt help

Comment: After you started the docker instance, you can access the container's shell by using command `docker exec -it myapp /bin/bash`. Then you can go to `/app` and check if `tasks.py` file is updated or not. Mind you may need to run `apt` to install an editor inside the container.

Comment: @PhilipTzou the `tasks.py` is updated. I think this is somehow a supervisor issue

Comment: @Jonathan, can you use the `-f` and `-l` arguments to save the debug level logs of Celery somewhere and post it here? See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-f

Comment: Note the difference between a docker image and a container. A `docker build` creates a new image (with a different sha hash), a `docker run` takes an image to run as a container, a `docker restart` will restart a running container from the existing sha image hash (even if the image has been recreated with the same name, a restart won't receive those changes). So you must `docker rm` and `docker run` to see the changes to the image.

Comment: I had similar problem of duplicated workers using `docker` on `windows` but I don't think it's the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be the problem:

```
@celery.task()  # <-- you shouldn't call this decorator directly
def add_together(a, b):
    return a+ b
```

Try changing it to this:

```
@celery.task
def add_together(a, b):
    return a+ b
```

The reason: just check the [source code of decorator `task`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v3.1.24/celery/app/base.py#L252):

```
def task(self, *args, **opts):
    """Creates new task class from any callable."""

    # ... handling named options

    if len(args) == 1:
        if callable(args[0]):
            return inner_create_task_cls(**opts)(*args)
        raise TypeError('argument 1 to @task() must be a callable')
    if args:
        raise TypeError(
            '@task() takes exactly 1 argument ({0} given)'.format(
                sum([len(args), len(opts)])))
    return inner_create_task_cls(**opts)
```

The only unnamed argument it accepted is the function to be decorated. Otherwise it would raise a `TypeError` and be swallowed by `supervisord` since you didn't configure [the `loglevel` to `debug`](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisord-section-values).

Comment: Hi @Philip, thanks for the tip but this doesnt help as well.

Comment: @Jonathan Well did you get some output by configuring the log level and log file?

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce your problem on my setup. I created a simple Flask app as in the Celery documentation.

Can you try a few commands to double check your setup?

Open a shell into myapp container (it must be already running):

```
docker exec -t -i myapp /bin/bash
```

And then:

```
cd /app
celery -A tasks.celery status
celery -A tasks.celery inspect registered
```

Does the new task show up?

I think you may have other celery instances connected to the same redis server, that's why you have 21 instances. But I'm guessing.

You can also try with an independent redis container.

```
docker run --name myredis -d redis
```

And execute celery in debug mode, with:

```
docker run --rm -t -i -v $(pwd)/app:/app -e REDIS_IP=myredis -u nobody -w /app --link myredis myapp celery -A tasks.celery worker -P eventlet -c 1000 -l debug
```

Is the task there now? It should be listed just bellow Celery startup banner message.

I don't think you have a problem with your image, but you can double check that looking into:

```
docker exec myapp /bin/bash -c "cat /app/tasks.py"
```

I don't think this is the problem because you copy /app into the image and when you run the container, you map /app again using the local directory. Are you running the container from the same directory you built the container?

The -v $(pwd)/app:/app will override /app in the container with current directory ./app. Do you really need this? Without the -v part, do you have the same results?

I hope it helps to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I made a working repo of your code.  It lives [here](https://github.com/bwarren2/SO_bounty_answer).

Things I changed:

- Colon typo (look at your `multiply` def)
- Not calling decorators
- General code cleanup
- Using a single redis URI
- Some directory navigation in my test

I did not focus on the supervisord parts.